# Missing property FieldInfo.FieldHandle in WinRT/UWP apps

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine, windows-10, uwp

I'm currently porting a Unity game to WinRT/Universal Windows Platform(UWP) or whatever you call it now. 
My game uses a plugin from the assetstore which heavily uses reflection and i have the problem that the property FieldInfo.FieldHandle does not exist.

For example here is a method which uses the FieldHandle property

```
public void InitFromComponent(Component component)
{
    m_ComponentType = component.GetType();

    m_Fields.Clear();

    foreach (FieldInfo f in m_ComponentType.GetFields())
    {
        if (f.IsPublic)
        {
            if (f.FieldType == typeof(float)
            || f.FieldType == typeof(Vector4)
            || f.FieldType == typeof(Vector3)
            || f.FieldType == typeof(Vector2)
            || f.FieldType == typeof(int)
            || f.FieldType == typeof(bool)
            || f.FieldType == typeof(string))
            {
                m_Fields.Add(new Field(f.FieldHandle, f.GetValue(component)));
            }
        }
    }
}

public Field(RuntimeFieldHandle fieldHandle, object args)
{
    FieldHandle = fieldHandle;
    Args = args;
}
```

So is there a way to get the RuntimeFieldHandle on WinRT?

Comment: Why do you even need `FieldHandle`; what are you doing with it? maybe you can ask the that question directly instead of [XyQuestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm using a third party plugin which makes use of this multiple times